# Model class is still not found on Laravel 4

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-4

I am creating an app in Laravel 4.2 and when I create a model, I get an exception that it's not found:

models/Annulations.php :

```
class Annulation extends Eloquent {
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'annulation_remboursement';
```

controllers/AnnulationsController.php :

```
class AnnulationsController extends \BaseController {
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $annulations = Annulation::all();
    return View::make('Annulations.index')->withAnnulations($annulations);
}
```

On stackoverflow, i found the solution about a command :

```
$ php artisan dump-autoload
```

If i try this command then I have still this error :
Class 'Annulation' not found

Could you help me?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your model **Annulations** the your class **should** be `class Annulations`.

For example:

folder path: **models/Annulations**

```
 class Annulations extends Eloquent{
  //logic here
 }
```

In your controller:

```
    public function someController(){

     $annulations = Annulations::all(); //call your model
     print_r($annulations); //print to check if data exists
     return View::make('Annulations.index')->withAnnulations($annulations);

    }
```